# Enable wlan0 and wlan1

Tags: wifi, wireless-adapter

I want to connect to my WiFi network to the wlan0 and use wlan1 to provide WiFi to my devices. Is it possible to enable two wlans without using an USB adapter?

Comment: It *might* be. There's a lot of information in [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=138730) discussion on the raspberrypi.org forums, but I'm not sure it came to a definitive conclusion.